# Separating greps output blockwise

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

Let's assume I have a programm that prompts a lot of information. I'm interested in only 3 messages which appear always after each other. I now want to grep these lines and separate them from the next 3 messages matching my pattern.

What I have so far is the following command line:

```
./myproc | grep -e "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" | awk '{print $0,"\n"}'
```

However this produces something like that

```
line 1

line 2 

line 3

line 1

line 2 

line 3
```

But what I want should look like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3

line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Comment: If you're doing `awk` already why use `grep` at all?  `awk` can do the pattern matching for you

Comment: Only print the newline after matching pattern 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't and shouldn't use grep when you pass the output to awk anyway, because awk knows what grep knows and even more.

Then, awk's print instruction (unlike printf() in C or print in perl) prints newline after the value automatically (although awk also has its own printf which does not).

And last bnl, if you just want to print out the whole record (here: line), you don't even have to specify it.

Now, you should try this:

```
./myproc | awk '/pattern1/,/pattern3/ {print}; /pattern3/ {print ""}'
```

And you should read about **range pattern** in **man awk**.